# How can I fix scrolling and layout issues when using react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am currently having an issue where using a StackNavigator (created using createStackNavigator) is messing up the layout of my component.

I have attached images to explain the problem! You can see, on the first run of the app, when I just directly render the view, the component renders fine. Then, when I change it to render my navigator (whose component is the same StartPartyPageView), the layout gets messed up.

Also, when rendering within a navigator, I am unable to scroll my scroll view.

Does anyone know what could be going on here?

This is where it is working:
[image: THIS IS WHERE IT IS WORKING]

This is where it is not working:
[image: THIS IS WHERE IT IS NOT WORKING]

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question and include relevant code parts as plain text, not as image.